# Write dataframe to text file as JSON-encoded dictionaries with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large text file containing JSON-encoded dictionaries line by line.

```
{"a": 10, "b": 11, "c": 12, "d": 13, "e": 14, "f": 15, "g": 16, "h": 17, "i": 18, "j": 19}
{"a": 20, "b": 21, "c": 22, "d": 23, "e": 24, "f": 25, "g": 26, "h": 27, "i": 28, "j": 29}
...
```

I am using Pandas because it allows me to easily rename and reindex the dictionary keys.

```
with open("my_dictionaries.txt") as f:
    my_dicts = [json.loads(line.strip()) for line in f]

df = pd.Dataframe(my_dicts)
df.rename(columns= ...)
df.reindex(columns= ...)
```

Now I want to write the altered dictionaries back to a text file, line by line, like the original example. I don't want to use `pd.to_csv()` because my data has some quirks that make a CSV more difficult to use. I have been experimenting with the `pd.to_dict()` and `pd.to_json()` methods but am a bit stuck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import json

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for row in  df.to_dict('records'):
        f.write(json.dumps(row) + '\n')
```

or:

```
import json

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines([(json.dumps(r) + '\n') for r in df.to_dict('records')])
```